# Bootstrap full width sections with graphical backgrounds

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement a design from my graphic designer, which whilst looks cool is giving me some headaches as i don't know how to implement in bootstrap.

We have a call to action section, which aligns with the 12 column grid system on its left and right extremes.

It also stretches to the view-port edges:

1. On the left we have red background stretching all the way to the view-port edge.
2. On the right we have a grey background image stretching all the way to the view-port edge.

I haven't been able to find a search term for what I am looking to achieve let alone where to start (other than have the cta use the background for the entire width, then overlay a left element over the top).

**Any idea on how to code the below graphical layout in bootstrap please**?

```
<section class="cta" style="background: grey; position: relative">
    <div class="red" style="position: absolute; left: 0; width: 10%; background: red"></div>
    <div class="text-outer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">left</div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">right</div>               
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>      
</section>
```

[image: cta]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do, but for one thing, any `col-md-<x>` divs need to be wrapped by a `.row`.

Comment: Thanks sorry long day, fixed and now wrapping cols - I am trying to implement the image posted in the question in bootstrap... it is an area of a page for a call to action section.

Comment: we might need to see more HTML before we can help you... right now, it is not clear (to me) what you have done and what is missing (or not working)

Comment: @g18c CSS is totally needed, you have a stylesheet other than bootstrap?

Comment: no i am totally happy to use custom styles is fine, kind of blew my mind on the alignment of the left hexagon to the first left column of the bootstrap grid

Comment: [Some good info for you here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)

Answer (score 0):

Using `<div class="container-fluid">` as a starting point; I am guessing at your page's layout. Let's try this:

See below:

```css
.cntn {
  border: 1px red solid;  /* you can remove this (not needed) */
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0;   /* optional */
  width: 100px; /* adjust to suit your needs */
  float: left;
}
.cta {
  margin: 0;  /* optional */
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid green;  /* you can remove this (not needed) */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- make container fluid -->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- heading area: hexagon -->
    <div class="red">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100/100" />
    </div>

    <!-- heading area: call-to-action -->
    <section class="cta">
      Action
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="row cntn">
    <div class="col-xs-6">left</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">right</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to post ochi, not quite if you can see the image from my original question, you will see that hexagon on the left. This should be in line with the first column of the 12-colum grid. Then the red bar (of which the hexagon is a part) bleeds off all the way to the edge (which could be quite far if the browser viewport is stretched wide). The remaining grey graphic bleeds off all the way to the right of the browser viewport right up to the edge.

Comment: Sorry, no - I am not understanding you.  could you post a [mcve] to the original question and maybe I'll understand you better.  The hexagon stretches wide because you have added a hard width of 10% (so the bigger the screen, the wider the gap) while your hexagon image is probably limited in size.  This is all a guess since we don't have all the code needed.  Post it and someone will come up with an answer quickly :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Where black should be the grey gradient and `max-width:400px` could be anything.

```css
.cta {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative
}

.text-outer .container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  background: grey;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}

.text-outer:before,
.text-outer:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.text-outer:before {
  background-color: red;
  left: 0;
}

.text-outer:after {
  background-color: black;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="cta">
  <div class="text-outer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">left</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">right</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change 'div class="container"' to 'div class="container-fluid"'

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddleLink](https://jsfiddle.net/Anand349g/hxzg7kaw/2/)

I created with 3 divs as Left Center and Right but if you want to use Left and center then create your own class. Probably following will work

```
.custom {
    width:calc(100% - (50% - 768px/2));
}

.custom {
    width:calc(100% - leftCellWidth);
}
```

You can set height of left as per height of hex image.

Answer (score 0):

Use `jumbotron` class outside the class `container` for full-width, as explained [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#jumbotron).

HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
   <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="red col-xs-4">
        </div>
        <div class="grey col-xs-8">
        </div>
     </div
   </div>     
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.red {
  background: url('awesomeredimage.png');
  background-size: cover;
}
.grey {
  background: url('awesomegreyimage.png');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All your divs should be wrapped in the container div. And as some others have also suggested: container-fluid helps.
Within container fluid you can add a regular container for the rest of your content. My code below explains this.

You could take the easy route and just use the entire cta image you've posted as a clickable image with .img-responsive in a col-xs-12. In that case my fix takes you about 2 minutes:

```
<section style="background: grey; position: relative">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <img src="/img/cta.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="container">
                    <!-- All you other content here-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

But you could also hack the design into cols, as I try to show in the code snippet below. Of course you need to tweak and decide on the exact sizes yourself.

```
<section style="background: grey; position: relative">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3 red">
                <img src="/img/hexagon.png" class="img-responsive pull-right">
                <!--and give this img a negative margin to flow over to the grey area-->
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1 grey-image"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 grey-image">
                <h3 class="text-center">Call to action</h3>
                <p class="text-center">Discount etcetera</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5 grey-image">
                <button class="btn center-block">Request quote</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="container">
                    <!-- All you other content here-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `class="container-fluid"` instead of `class="container"` and than do this style:

```
.container-fluid {
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Overriding `.container-fluid` result in a catastrophic breakdown throughout the page.

Comment: Than maybe you have to explain better what you wanna do or understand better what container-fluid does instead of giving me a minus. This is an example for you to see http://www.bootply.com/121222. Anyway thanks bro.

Comment: `.container-fluid` is something that you use throughout a bootstrap page. Overriding that on later part with changes like `padding` might and in some cases will break the site.

I didn't give you a minus, I gave your answer a minus. So that someone looking for a solution doesn't try something like this. And I am not bound to come up with a better solution in this case.

Comment: Anyway Here is a better solution: Instead of overriding a bootstrap class create your own. `.container-fluid-custom` and then write your own properties here. You will use it where you want it and nothing else you did before will be effected.

Comment: I dont know in which platform are you using or what framework or are you using bootstrap or not. But i also know that you can style a global class in a single view and keep the css in the view or just link it in a separated file only with that view not affecting in other places that you have used that class.

Comment: I am not talking about other views. It will change things in the same view. Things that you have done before you decided to override the class. Now if you **have** to override a class then instead of putting in another css file to the view. You can just add a special class. e.g. `.padding-0{ padding:0 }` , and then call it at the same element you have `.container-fluid`